# Case Closed - Pass JSON data to Controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass this data from my view to save it via controller.

My view

```
<div>
    <b>Title</b> <br /> 
    <input type="text" id="title" /><br />
    <b>Description</b> <br /> 
    <input type="text" id="desc" /><br />   
</div>
<button id="saveDetails">Save</button>
```

My js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#saveDetails", saveDetails);
    $("#detailsPanel").hide();
});

var saveDetails = function () {
    var dataPost = {
        "Title": $("#title").val(),
        "Description": $("#desc").val(),
        "AssetId": $("#assetId").val()
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataPost),
        url: "/Media/Save"
    }).done(function (state) {
        if (state.Saved == true) {
            displayStatusMessage("Saved Successfully");
            $("#detailsPanel").hide();
            mediaPlayer.initFunction("videoDisplayPane", state.StreamingUrl);
        } else {
            displayStatusMessage("Save Failed");            
        }
    });
}
```

My Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(MediaElement mediaelement)
    {
        try
        {
            mediaelement.UserId = User.Identity.Name;
            mediaelement.FileUrl = GetStreamingUrl(mediaelement.AssetId);
            db.MediaElements.Add(mediaelement);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { Saved = true, StreamingUrl = mediaelement.FileUrl });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Saved = false });
        }
    }
```

Its already post the data to my controller (i saw it via Fiddler), but it always return Json(new { Saved = false }).

Anything wrong with my code? Need help, please...

**[Case Closed]**

Okay, I found in my db, i have coloumn UploadDate which is not null. And I already declare the default value on my db with this -> getdate(). But it doesnt work when I inserted data from controller. So i add the value of UploadDate manually via Controller. Then Its Works:)

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and see the details of the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: @KellyGendron I already add code to pass the exception when return false, but there is no exception that being thrown

Comment: if it return false, ex may contains an exception ...

Comment: if you put a breakpoint at the beginning of the `try`, what is the value of `mediaElement`?

Comment: If you've found a solution, **please consider posting the answer** (and not putting it in your question as an edit).

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with the MediaElement model binding ...
but before, check the folowing :

1. you can try to remove the JSON type of your ajax.
2. your json format.
3. the dataPost var miss the ; end.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
> $(document).on("click", "#saveDetails", saveDetails);
> $("#detailsPanel").hide();
> });
>
> var saveDetails = function () {
> var dataPost = {
>     Title: $("#title").val(),
>     Description: $("#desc").val(),
>     AssetId: $("#assetId").val()
> };
> $.ajax({
>     type: "POST",
>     async: false,
>
>     data: dataPost,
>     url: "/Media/Save"
> }).done(function (state) {
>     if (state.Saved == true) {
>         displayStatusMessage("Saved Successfully");
>         $("#detailsPanel").hide();
>         mediaPlayer.initFunction("videoDisplayPane", state.StreamingUrl);
>     }
>     else {
>         displayStatusMessage("Saved Failed");
>     }
> });
> }
> ```